# Does mkProgram expose more functionality than mkSimple?

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

I am trying to understand the difference between mkSimple and mkProgram in Fable-Elmish, or Elmish.WPF which I am actually using. (Can someone perhaps produce a tag for elmish.wpf please?)

I have found Elmish.WPF to be incredibly effective, I use it in production, but I'm at a stage where I'm still learning a lot every day. This particular question is gobbling up too much of my research time, so I would appreciate some help.

The comments in the source looks like this.

mkSimple : `Simple program that produces only new state with 'init' and 'update'.`

mkProgram : `Typical program, new commands are produced by 'init' and 'update' along with the new state.`

So what are those commands good for? I have looked at examples in several places, but they don't give much of a clue whether I can do the same with mkSimple as with mkProgram, and that's what I need to know.

**Does mkProgram expose some functionality that mkSimple does not, or can everything be done whichever one I use?** Is mkSimple only for simple demo use, and should I be using mkProgram for real world applications that grow? If you can do everything with both, then why the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mkSimple` is really only for learning purposes. It helps ease new users into the framework by not introducing the ideas of `Cmd` yet.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/fable-elmish/elmish/blob/master/src/program.fs#L43-L53) of `mkSimple`, you will see that all it is doing is hiding the `Cmd` idea (by using `Cmd.none`) and calling `mkProgram`:

```fsharp
/// Simple program that produces only new state with `init` and `update`.
let mkSimple 
    (init : 'arg -> 'model) 
    (update : 'msg -> 'model -> 'model)
    (view : 'model -> Dispatch<'msg> -> 'view) =
    { init = init >> fun state -> state,Cmd.none
      update = fun msg -> update msg >> fun state -> state,Cmd.none
      view = view
      setState = fun model -> view model >> ignore
      subscribe = fun _ -> Cmd.none
      onError = onError }
```

Its origins are from the Elm Architecture, which has since renamed the simple program to [`beginnerProgram`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#beginnerProgram).

If you want to want to write a program with any complexity, use `mkProgram`. If you are merely tinkering or demonstrating the basics, you *may* be able to use `mkSimple`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think you have brought me a giant leap forward, since I believe the answer to my next challenges lies in exploiting exactly those commands, and now I'll switch to mkProgram and learn how it all works.